# Is possible to create new account in salesforce ?

Tags: php, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I want to create new user account in sales-force using email address in php. is possible that ?

Comment: You want to create User or Account..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a perfect tutorial i find out - http://ahmeddirie.com/technology/web-development/salesforce-php-soap-api-creating-contacts-accounts-and-associating-records/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Salesforce provides an API & PHP Toolkit that you can use to create any type of Salesforce object (e.g. accounts, contacts, contracts, etc.)

Check out https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit

Answer (score 0):

I found this page useful: http://www.blacktabgroup.com/keeping-tabs/posts/2013/january/importing-new-user-records-overview-of-the-required-fields.aspx

I would create or find a user that is similar to what you want to bulk create and export that user with all fields so you can see the values.